# Controlling font weight dependent on mouse position on the screen

Tags: javascript, variables, fonts

I'm using [ABC Dinamo](https://abcdinamo.com/news/using-variable-fonts-on-the-web)'s resource on variable fonts but am getting a bit stuck. I'm trying to control font weight in relation to the user's mouse movements, for which they provide this script:

```
function updateText(e) {
  multiplierWidth = e.offsetX / window.innerWidth;
  multiplierHeight = e.offsetY / window.innerHeight;
  randomWeight =  multiplierWidth * (200 - 35) + 35;
  randomWidth =  multiplierHeight * (200 - 100) + 100;
  myText.style.fontVariationSettings = "\"wght\" " + randomWeight + ", \"wdth\" " + randomWidth;
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateText)
```

However, the font I'm using only has one variable axis, weight, from 200 to 800. The code they provide is for a font that has two, weight and width.

I've tried to use the code as is (but with 'myText.style' replaced with the h7 tag I need to use), but that doesn't work. I've tried using this edited version, but it doesn't work either:

```
function updateText(e) {
  multiplierWidth = e.offsetX / window.innerWidth;
  multiplierHeight = e.offsetY / window.innerHeight;
  randomWeight =  multiplierWidth * (200 - 35) + 35;
  h7.fontVariationSettings = "\"wght\" " + randomWeight;
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateText)
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please? Am I missing parts of the script? The guide is useful to a point but I think it's not quite clear enough for script novices like me!

Comment: see that they set the attribute to `myText.style` and not to `myText` you should set it `h7.style.fontVariationSettings`, great you are experimenting with variable fonts!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've updated the code but it's still not working.

Comment: It's nothing that couldn't be done. Try to console.log all the values to see if everything is alright. There must be just some small problem. How do you know the range of weight in this font for example? Are those correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm such a novice that I don't know what a console.log is, but I'll look into it now. The font's weight range is 200 to 800 when I bring it into Illustrator and InDesign, so I'm assuming that it's the case in the webfont too.

Comment: So when I use the console to inspect the page I'm using the scrip on I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: h7 is not defined at updateText ((index):209)"

And it highlights this line:

"  h7.style.fontVariationSettings = "\"wght\" " + randomWeight; "

Comment: Yes, that is because you don't have it defined.. I guess that h7 is a headline of level of 7? so tag h7? Are there multiple of those? I would recommend starting with one. Make one div or whatever that has id of `h7` and then say `h7 = document.getElementById("h7")`. If you manage this you can move forward.. there can be for example a div in which you add `<style>...</style>` with javascript, this would contain css definition for your h7

Comment: It worked! I had to change the number range in the code too. I thought it was something to do with screen dimensions but it was the weight range of the font. I change (200 - 35) to (800 - 200). Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, after inspecting your variable font, it seems not to be a variable font. I talk specifically about `TGFrekuentMonoVariable.ttf`. Are you sure you are using the correct font?

Comment: That's weird. It's the file I was given by the company who designed it, and it works fine in my adobe design programs. I'll look into it and contact the font designer

Comment: It was something to do with the file, must have been corrupted somehow as when I downloaded the same file again and rreplaced it on my server it worked. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Maybe it's because it was a varible OTF file with CFF compresion. Didn't you compressed it into TTF yourself? Then the compressor could break the variable table inside the font.

Comment: I downloaded the ttf from the designer but converted it to the woff, woff2 formats etc myself. All sorted now so all good, thanks again